# Issue with window.open alignment in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

We have a page hosted on another server, when user logged into our application they can navigate to this external page by clicking on a button.

The page opening at left-bottom corner without any issue in Google chrome, however when we tried in IE the window is opening however, the page is looing like going to the screen.[image]

Code:

```
myWindow = window.open("mysite.com",
                       '',
                       'resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, status=yes, width=' + 1500 / systemZoom +
                       ', height=' + 500 / systemZoom +
                       ', top=' + top +
                       ', left=' + left);
```

Comment: There's basically nothing you can do about how `window.open()` works other than requesting a window size, and even that might be overridden by user browser settings (like "always open in a new tab").

Comment: can u plz send the code?

Comment: Thanks, I have added code in Question

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code to display the popup window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
        window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);            
    } 
</script>

<a href="javascript:popupwindow('https://www.google.com','google','900','500');  ">This is the link</a>
```